# How to display query generated by prefetch_related

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a QuerySet with a `prefetch_related()` (with `Prefetch` object)

I want to see the raw query and `print(qs.query)` and it doesn't show anything about the `prefetch_related` stuff.

How do I see the query which will be run because of `prefetch_related`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The queryset's `query` object will only show you the query that Django generates for the queryset itself (before any `prefetch_related` etc. is applied).

You probably need to look at [these guidelines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running) for inspecting the query that is actually sent to your database:

```
from django.db import connection
print(connection.queries)
```

Alternatively you can use something like [django-debug-toolbar](https://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to display the queries.